# How to fix these warning messages -- com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, increment: 1

Tags: spring, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am using Couchbase java SDK 2.7.9 with spring boot project but my console/log files are getting filled up with these warning message

```
 com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, increment: 1
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release0(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:90) ~[core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:74) ~[core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release(ReferenceCountUtil.java:59) ~[core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.safeRelease(ReferenceCountUtil.java:84) ~[core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove0(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:292) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.failFlushed(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:617) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.closeOutboundBufferForShutdown(AbstractChannel.java:627) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.shutdownOutput(AbstractChannel.java:620) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:893) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:313) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:847) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1266) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:743) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:743) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:533) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:358) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:743) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1500(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:35) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$16.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:464) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [core-io-1.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
```

is there a way to handle these warning messages?

Comment: I was able to solve this by setting bufferPoolingEnabled to false.

Answer (score 0):

We think we started getting these with 2.7.9 also...  2.7.4 didn't seem to have this problem.  I do not know about the middling versions.

See: https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/JCBC-1333

Seems like you'd need the Crypto library as well...

Comment: i was able to solve this problem by settingbufferPoolingEnabled to false in couchbase Enviornment class.